# How to save and then update same class instance during one request with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, entity, save

I'm relatively new to NHibernate and I've got a question about it.
I use this code snippet in my MVC project in Controller's method:

```
MyClass entity = new MyClass 
                    {
                        Foo = "bar"
                    };

_myRepository.Save(entity);

....

entity.Foo = "bar2";
_myRepository.Save(entity);
```

The first time entity saved in database succesfully. But the second time not a single request doesnt go to database. My method save in repository just does:

```
public void Save(T entity)
{
  _session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
}
```

What should I do to be able to save and then update this entity during one request? If I add `_session.Flush();` after saving entity to database it works, but I'm not sure, if it's the right thing to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior.

- Changes are only saved on `Flush`
- `Flush` may be called explicitly or implicitly (see [9.6. Flush](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing))
- When using an `identity` generator (not recommended), inserts are sent immediately, because that's the only way to return the ID.

Comment: Hmm, my inserts are sent immediately, though I haven't configured anything special. I use fluent nhibernate to map my classes to database tables. And just use this line of code to map the id: `Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");`

Comment: This is what I use in NinjectModule:
  `public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider<SessionFactoryBuilder>()
                .InSingletonScope();
            Bind<ISession>()
                .ToMethod(CreateSession)
                .InRequestScope();    
   Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>();
   .... 
        }
  private static ISession CreateSession(Ninject.Activation.IContext context)
        {
            var session = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession();
            return session;
        }`

Answer (score 2):

you should be using transactions.
a couple of good sources: [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/09/08/part-9-nhibernate-transactions.aspx) and [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged).
also, [summer of nHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) is how I first started with nHibernate. it's a very good resource for learning the basics.